# I am unable to conect to Tor from an specific country IP

Tags: relays, ip-address

I have been using Tor for a time now. I had it configured to conect from an Irish IP since that is what I need. It was always working okay but now suddenly it won't conect itself.

I had the IP set by adding: `ExitNodes {ie}` in the `torccdefaults` file. Everything was okay until yesterday when I tried to open it and it got stucked loading, "requesting relay information". If I delete that added script from the file it opens perfectly, but when i add it again it gets stucked once again. It was working smoothly until now, any idea what the problem might be and how can i fix it?

Works with every country except for Ireland.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make sense. You're trying to force it to use an exit in a specific country, that won't stop Tor connecting it will just stop it working if there are no exits in that country, even then it'll still work it just won't use the country in question. Post your Tor logs and your torrc.

Comment: This is my torcc ExitNodes {ie}
# torrc-defaults for Tor Browser
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# This file is distributed with Tor Browser and SHOULD NOT be modified (it
# may be overwritten during the next Tor Browser update). To customize your
# Tor configuration, shut down Tor Browser and edit the torrc file.
#
# If non-zero, try to write to disk less frequently than we would otherwise.
AvoidDiskWrites 1
# Where to send logging messages. Format is minSeverity[-maxSeverity]
# (stderr|stdout|syslog|file FILENAME).
Log notice stdout
CookieAuthentication 1
## fteproxy configuration
ClientTranspor

Comment: If you're not an expert why are you trying to do stupid shit with country codes which will harm your anonymity, potentially entirely deanonymizing you?

Comment: That was unnecesarily rude. I need to connect to an Irish IP to access to a SAFE (https) website that i cant access other way.

Comment: @Mark, it sounds like a VPN may be better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ireland is one of the countries which has only a [few Tor relays](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/country:ie). If you search for [exit relays in Ireland](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/country:ie%20flag:exit) Tor metrics currently shows no results. This means that at the moment there is no exit relay in Ireland. So it is not possible to exit from Tor in Ireland.